# Why map literals in Go allow overwriting keys when using a function call instead of a literal?

Tags: dictionary, go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    blaa := map[string]string{
        "key":    "value",
        getKey(): "value2", //replacing getKey() with "key" results in compile time error.
    }
    fmt.Println("Hello, " + blaa["key"])
}

func getKey() string {
    return "key"
}
```

Running the above program will print "Hello, value2". Try it here https://go.dev/play/p/s92LaaNc3n4

While I can see the key gets overwritten, I'm wondering why this doesn't `panic` at runtime? Using two string literals `"key"` will result in a compilation time error, which is the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 9):

A map literal of the form:

```
blaa := map[string]string{
        "key":    "value",
        "key": "value2", 
    }
```

is a compile-time error, because all values are known at compile time, and a map with duplicate keys is an invalid map literal.

The following is computed at runtime:

```
blaa := map[string]string{
        "key":    "value",
        getKey(): "value2", 
    }
```

This creates a map literal with one element, and then sets the second element using the result of the given function.

Rewriting a key is a valid operation, that's why it does not panic.

Comment: All of this has been already stated in my question. I'm trying to understand the rationale behind the language design here. They could've chosen that have two literal keys "key" results in an overwrite - at compile time - by the second key, but instead opted for a compile time error which sounds reasonable.

Comment: There is not much of a choice there, it is simply an invalid literal, similar to `var a int=1.3` being a compile error. A map contains unique keys, so a map literal with duplicate keys is an invalid literal.